# Entity Framework data insertion bad performance for a database with 750 tables

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

we have written a simple code to generate 750 classes with names from MyObj0 to MyObj749, each class has 1 int (ID) and 10 string properties, no navigation properties and no foreign keys for a start.

The reason we're doing this is that we'd love to use EF but our production databases contain cca 700 - 800 tables.

This is a sample of the first class.

```
public class MyObj0
{
    public int MyObj0ID { get; set; }
    public string Name0 { get; set; }
    public string Name1 { get; set; }
    public string Name2 { get; set; }
    public string Name3 { get; set; }
    public string Name4 { get; set; }
    public string Name5 { get; set; }
    public string Name6 { get; set; }
    public string Name7 { get; set; }
    public string Name8 { get; set; }
    public string Name9 { get; set; }
}
```

The DbContext class

```
class Db : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyObj0> MyObj0s { get; set;}
    public DbSet<MyObj1> MyObj1s { get; set;}
    ...
    public DbSet<MyObj749> MyObj749s { get; set;}
}
```

Then comes the testing.

```
Database.SetInitializer<Db>(null); //comment this line to create the DB

Stopwatch stopw = new Stopwatch();
stopw.Start();

Db db = new Db();
db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
Console.WriteLine("Db init: " + stopw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString());

stopw.Restart();

db.MyObj0s.Add(new MyObj0() { Name0 = "name" });

Console.WriteLine("Row insertion: " + stopw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString());

stopw.Restart();

db.SaveChanges();

Console.WriteLine("Save changes: " + stopw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString());

Console.ReadLine();
return;
```

And the result?

```
Db init: 616,3831 
(which is ok if we consider that this happens only 
 when the application starts)

Row insertion: 7663,673 
(7 seconds to insert a row. Not ok at all.)

Save changes: 3647,1969 
(3 seconds to insert a row into the database. Not ok at all)
```

Are there any performance catches for EF we haven't came across yet? Or is EF at this stage unsuitable for large databases? 
(We've used it for plenty small projects and it's running pretty smooth there)

**EDIT**

Per Ladislav's question:

Trying to insert another row after the first row is much faster. 0,0562 miliseconds. 
Unfortunately, SaveChanges operation still takes approx. 3500 ms

After another observing, I found out that while inserting the first row, the application is consuming a lot of memory, from just a few megabytes to around 65 megabytes and it jumps another 10mb after calling SaveChanges. So it seems to me there are some initialization procedures for the first row operations I haven't learned about yet.

Still, knowing this, I could easily avoid the lag for the first operation if I insert some dummy data when the app starts. 
(The application starting time doesn't matter since it'd be used in a web project and everyone, even the clients, expect some sort of lag during the deployment)

Could anyone explain the behavior behind this? I trully think we've have just omitted something important...

**EDIT 2**

After another toying, I found out that calling another SaveChanges() takes almost nothing as well, 0,05 ms. So we could happily insert a dummy row then call a SaveChanges() and everything should work just fine. But this approach is just ... not good. Have I forgotten some sort of initializing? Because I have no idea, what else is important apart from the function SetInitializer...

Comment: I have used EF with databases containing over a 1000 tables. Why are you recreating the database every time?

Comment: What is the difference if you try to add two records?

Comment: Sean Barlow: Why do you think I recreate the database every time? The line with SetInitializer(null) ought to skip the database creation

Comment: Ladislav Mrkna: inserting the second row is almost instant, see my response in the bottom part of the question